# The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:00 error for autocompleteextender

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I get this error.

> The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

I am using an `automcompleteextender` which calls a `[webmethod]` which in turn calls a `WCF service`. The problem is when i enter 3 letters at a time the service call freezes. The extender never works. No other `autocompleteextender` works on the page later.

I have already tried setting `sendTimeout` and `maxReceivedMessageSize`. It doesnt help.

Please provide a word around.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is inside the WCF service. For diagnostics, try calling the service directly from a test client with your "3 letter" requests to see what the service is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i solved the issue. It was really strange on how it got solved.

I had to change the binding from `WsHttpBinding` to `BasicHttpBinding`

Everything else remained the same. It was just the `Binding`